# How to enable "Abbreviations" on code blocks on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

[image: Abbreviation]

I'm new user on Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 14.04. Here, while I install code blocks I found that "Abbreviations" is not enabled here. Now how can I enable this on my code blocks 13.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question and for using for using code-blocks IDE.

The abbreviations functionality has become a plug-in, which you should also install after a new install of code-blocks.

type in console:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```

and your abbreviation functionality should be back :)

regards

Hewi